# How to replace a frame (rgb image) in a small video sequence?

Tags: matlab, video, video-processing

I want to replace a single rgb frame in a 4 sec video sequence, example i want to replace the 5th frame with my rgb image of same dimension as the video dimension (example 256x256)
in MATLAB

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to read your video:

```
v = VideoReader('myvideo.myformat');
```

Then read all the frames and change the desired frame in your new video:

```
nv = VideoWriter('video.myformat');
open(nv)
counter = 0;
while hasFrame(v)
    counter = counter + 1;
    video = readFrame(v);
    if counter == 5
        writeVideo(nv,rand(256))
    else
        writeVideo(nv,video)
    end
end
```